# Create list of IDs of selected objects in an array

Tags: javascript

If I've got

```
var aaa = [
 {"id": 1, "text": "Ann"},
 {"id": 2, "text": "Bob"},
 {"id": 3, "text": "Carol"},
 {"id": 4, "text": "Carol"},
]
```

and I want to get all the elements that text "Carol" but specifically I want just their IDs.What do I do?

Comment: Use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). See also [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19590865/218196)

Comment: Use a for loop and if the object's `text` is `"Carol"`, push its `id` to an output array

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let idList = aaa.filter(a => a.text == 'Carol').map(({ id }) => id);
```